# Prevent awk from adding non-integers?

Tags: awk

I have a file that has these columns that I would like to add:

```
absolute_broad_major_cn
1
1
1
1
1.76
1.76
NA
1
```

and

```
absolute_broad_minor_cn
1
1
1
1
0.92
0.92
NA
1
```

I did `awk '{ print $1+$2 }`, which worked well but it put 0 for where there was an `NA`. Is it possible to make awk forget this and just put `NA` again instead (so awk only adds numbers)?

Edit: Desired output is:

```
<Column header> 
2
2
2
2
2.68
2.68
NA
2
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: `'{ if ( $1 ~ /^[0-9]*\.*[0-9]+$/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]*\.*[0-9]+$/ ) print $1 + $2; else print $1; }'`

Comment: When you say `non-integers`, you really men `non-numbers`, right? If your input is 1 file with 2 columns rather than 2 files each with 1 column as people are providing solutions for then [edit] your example to be accurate.

Answer (score 3):

```
paste absolute* | awk '{ if ($1 == "NA" && $2 == "NA") print "NA"; else print $1 + $2; }'
```

would do the trick; whether you want && (both are "NA" to produce an "NA") or || (either one is "NA" produces an NA) is specific to your need.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=$0
  next
}
{
  print ($0~/[a-zA-Z]/ && a[FNR]~/[a-zA-Z]/?"NA":a[FNR]+$0)
}
' absolute_broad_major_cn  absolute_broad_minor_cn
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                             ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                                          ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file absolute_broad_major_cn is being read.
  a[FNR]=$0                                                       ##Creating array a with index FNR and having value as current line here.
  next                                                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  print ($0~/[a-zA-Z]/ && a[FNR]~/[a-zA-Z]/?"NA":a[FNR]+$0)       ##Printing either addition of current line with array a value or print NA in case any alphabate is found either in array value OR in current line.
}
' absolute_broad_major_cn  absolute_broad_minor_cn                ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're really trying to do is sum 2 numeric columns from 1 file:

```
awk '{print ($1==($1+0) ? $1+$2 : $1)}' file
```

`$1 == $1+0` will only be true if $1 is a number.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the lines with NA & then add them
`awk '$1 != "NA"' FS=' ' file | awk '{ print $1+$2 }'`

Comment: Usually it is not necessary to pipe content from `awk` to `awk`. `awk` language is enough  for doing most things in single step. For example, your answer could be rewritten like `awk '$1 != "NA" { print $1+$2 }'`